# A Mainer Expression

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

```
+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+  
|  Box         |   Day        |   Files      |   Means      |  
+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+  
|  Love        |   Span       |   Objective  |   Pad        |  
+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+  
|  Tenacious   |   Sharp      |   Wave       |   Ray        |  
+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+  
|  Special     |   Section    |   Men        |   Pop        |  
+==============+==============+==============+==============+  
|  Step        |   Bit        |   Tone       |   Oz         |  
+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+  
|  Prop        |   Ground     |   Absolute   |   Mile       |  
+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+  
|  Hateful     |   Coke       |   Ball       |   Spirit     |  
+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+  
|  Beg         |   Patient    |   Face       |   Some       |  
+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

**What do they say in Maine?**

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Nice puzzle! In Maine, they say:

> **SUGAR MILK**!

Why? Well, first notice that what we have here are:

> Two connecting walls.

Furthermore, it turns out that:

> In the topmost wall the 4 connecting groups are all *individual letters*, while in the bottom-most wall the 4 connecting groups are *individual numbers*.

Like so:

> **WALL 1**
>
>  **Group 1: X**
>  **X**-box (games console)
>  **X**-Files (TV show)
>  **X**-Men (Marvel franchise)
>  **X**-Ray (medical imaging)
>
>  **Group 2: K**
>  **K**-LOVE (Christian radio station)
>  Special **K** (cereal)
>  **k**-means (a statistical test)
>  **K**-Pop (music genre)
>
>  **Group 3: C**
>  **C**-Span (TV channel)
>  Objective-**C** (programming language)
>  **C** Sharp (programming language)
>  **C**-Section (medical procedure)
>
>  **Group 4: D**
>  Tenacious **D** (comedy music duo)
>  **D**-Wave (Canadian quantum computing company)
>  **D**-Pad (games console controller)
>  **D**-Day (Normandy landings, WW2)
>
>  **WALL 2**
>
>  **Group 1: 2**
>
>  **Two** Step (dance)
>  **Two** Tone (music genre)
>  **Two**-Face (Batman baddie)
>  **Two**-Spirit (Native American term)
>
>  **Group 2: 1**
>
>  Prop**one** ("To bring before a jury or judge")
>  Beg**one**
>  Oz**one** (atmospheric layer)
>  Some**one**
>
>  **Group 3: 0**
>
>  Coke **Zero** (soft drink)
>  Ground **Zero** (disaster epicentre)
>  Patient **Zero** (first case in an epidemic)
>  Absolute **Zero** (coldest possible temperature)
>
>  **Group 4: 8**
>
>  Hateful **8** (movie)
>  **8**-Bit (computer architecture)
>  **8**-Ball (black pool ball)
>  **8**-Mile (movie)

Next, notice that:

> The positions of the groups as I have numbered them above correspond exactly across the two grids - i.e. the positions corresponding to elements in Group 1 (X) in Wall 1 exactly match those corresponding to elements in Group 1 (2) in Wall 2, and similarly for Groups numbered 2, 3 and 4:
>
>  [image]

From this, we should infer that:

> We can pair X with 2, K with 1, C with 0 and D with 8. In other words, we can arrange these ordered pairs to form **XKCD 2108** - and what else could this be but a reference to a certain well known web comic, where instalment #2108 is [this](https://xkcd.com/2108/)?
>
>  [image]

If we look at Maine specifically (the upper-rightmost state in the image) we see that:

> People from Maine would call their carbonated beverages "**SUGAR MILK**"!

Comment: both q and a are spectacular!

Comment: Explained perfectly.